# Where does Exchange 2010 store the STM file, does it even still use it?

Tags: exchange-2010

Our domain controller died, with no hope of recovering anything.  The AD backup died with it.  Due to no longer having a DC, our Exchange is unable to start.  I'm trying to use "Kernel for Exchange Server" to recover the mails that are in the mailbox store.  I've found the .edb file, but the .stm file is nowhere on the machine.

Does Exchange 2010 still use the .edb & .stm files, or is there a new store format?  If not, where will the .stm file be hiding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exchange 2010 doesn't uses stm files, since 2007 - no stm files
you can use kernel data recovery or ontrack power controls to restore your mailboxes from mailbox.edb - you would need logs and database files to have the most recent restores.

or

just mailbox.edb will do as well - when using the recovery tools.

Comment: Thank you.  When I run kernel for exchange on the file, it processes over 65000 item, but does not show anything.  I've tried all 3 recovery options that it has, as well as using eseutil to defrag the store.  Is there anything else that you can suggest for me to try?

Comment: Kernel also does not show that it goes past step 1 of 6, at step 1 it has > 65000 items to process, then the window disappears.  Is that relevant?

Comment: I just found out from their support desk that the application does not support the 2010 data files.  They said an update would be released around 11 June 2010 which would support it.

Comment: Go for Ontrack power controls for exchange
http://www.ontrackpowercontrols.co.uk/
it supports exchange 2010
they will give you a full functional trial - 14 days.

You may as well buy the tool as it is very useful and efficient.